SwiftUI TabBar show translucent effect even when scroll is over
iOS TabBar automatically shows a blurry effect when items scroll behind it, as shown in the image:

but once the content view scrolls to the bottom, the background goes transparent:

Is there any way to make the TabBar always fully visible including the translucent / blurry background?

You just need to apply .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar) to the content inside the TabView:
TabView {
    Text("MyView")
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .tabItem { Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle") }
}



Thank you @BenzyNeez, I was pretty sure I tried it, but I guess I applied it to the wrong view, it works like a charm :)
